# How to convert a local time to utc in php

Tags: php

I have a local time `09:45 AM`. How can i convert it into UTC format.
I tried something like this `gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', $busSchedule->end_time);` Here `$busSchedule->end_time` contains the local time. But it gave me an error

> A non well formed numeric value encountered

Comment: But firstly you need to change your `datetime` into `timestamp`

Comment: so i cant convert local time to utc directly???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
    $end_date_time = date("Y-m-d")." ".$busSchedule->end_time;
    echo $current_date_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s A",strtotime($end_date_time));
    echo "<br>";
    echo $utc_date_time = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s A",strtotime($current_date_time));
?>
```